# Spacing between inline-block divs, can't solve by removing whitespace

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this question has been asked on SO before, and the answer is usually to remove any spaces between the markup. In this case, I can't, since I'm programatically printing out divs:

```
<div class="products row">
  {{#each products}}
    {{> product}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

I won't bore you with the details of the `product` template, but suffice it to say, the template engine will dump out divs with either a space or newline in between each one.

What I'm trying to do is just close those gaps so I get all six divs in a row (no wrapping). Also, the divs need to be centered within the page (or their container). So whether I have two divs or six, they should always be centered.

Here's a JSFiddle showing the divs with bad spacing:

http://jsfiddle.net/6opf8ybs/

Is there some way to fix this in CSS? I heard the `font-size: 0` trick is not ideal.

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-center">
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-center">b</div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-center">d</div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-center">b</div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-center">d</div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-center">d</div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-center">d</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.row-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.col-center {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: left;
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: What spacing do you want? what is the goal here?

Comment: Edited! I want to remove the spacing so the last div doesn't wrap to a new line

Comment: Huh?  I'm not seeing that on your JSBin on Windoze/Chrome.. All output is on a single line...

Comment: Sigh. Someone keeps editing the JSbin. Look at the code above instead.

Comment: The code above looks normal? I'm confused.

Comment: Great sales pitch for jsfiddle... You know how to add CDN content to jsfiddle on left hand margin, no?

Comment: This is precisely why I maintain that `display: inline-block` is not suited for block layout. It's in the name: **inline**-block. The whitespace is there for a reason. Using inline-block for a layout then trying to remove inter-element whitespace after the fact is like building a house out of cheese and then trying to plug all the holes so water doesn't come out and walling up the cheese (*after* you've plugged the holes) so mice don't gobble it all up.

Comment: @BoltClock What's the alternative though? I need the divs side-by-side. But I can't use `float: left` otherwise the centering goes away. Whether there are three divs in that row or six, they need to be centered within the page.

Comment: Well I maintain, that a house built out of cheese sounds delicious. Especially Parmesan.

Comment: @TomSlick: All the more reason you don't want the mice getting to it before you do I suppose.

Comment: Is this a mobile issue?  I'm seeing the last element jump lines when the line width is less than 195 pixels or so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ty using a negative margin on the `inline-block` items.
Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cj93h04c/)

```
.col-center {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 -2px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I've heard that using negative margins is not ideal, but in this case it gets the job done (also on IE10). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: What if you changed the container display to flex?

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/toodgqmm/2

Comment: `float: none` isn't really the "issue" so much as you can't float an inline-block. When you set `float: left` you're effectively removing the inline-block.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post to clarify. The divs need to appear centered on the page.

Comment: Bootstrap, 2 times 6 = 12... what am I missing?

Comment: They look centered to me.

Comment: @zipzit Missing as far as what? Why it wraps?

Comment: Ah... it looks like if I drag the element narrower than 195pixels, the last element jumps to a new line...  Are you on a really narrow mobile phone?

Comment: That wrapping is inherent in bootstrap. It's going to happen at some point. Am I the only one who's still not grasping the issue here?

Comment: The issue is that all six divs should fit on the same row, and NOT wrap. I also want the divs to be centered on the page, hence changing the columns to `inline-block` and removing the float. So if I have three divs, they should center. If there are six, it should center. But when I hit six, it wraps due to spacing inserted between divs thanks to `inline-block`.

Comment: Sorry, someone miscopied my code into the fiddle. ARGH!!

Comment: @cocoa flexbox would be awesome, and that works, but not on IE10 which I need to support.

Comment: darn...i love flexbox. and not ie

Answer (score 0):

Let Bootstrap do its thing.  I'd recommend checking how many elements there are on a line, from within your code (JS).  If two elements they code out as

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-center">b</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-center">d</div>
```

if you have four elements they code out as

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-center">b</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-center">d</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-center">b</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-center">d</div>
```

etc.... 1*12 = 2*6 = 3*4 = 12... let Bootstrap work for you.  Obvious 5 elements in a single line will be a problem... (I'm assuming 6 elements max...)

Uh-oh.. is this an angular generated listing?  Have you looked at the stackoverflow tag `angular-ui-bootstrap`?

Comment: Nope, not Angular. Meteor.

Comment: I like the idea of changing the column widths but that would introduce a bunch of other issues I know my client would not like. I gotta stick with that exact column width.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use negative `margin` value like this below:

```
.col-center {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: left;
  float: none;
  margin-left:-2.5px;
  margin-right:-2.5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently found a solution to this problem:

```
.row-center {
  display: table;
  word-spacing: -2em;
  width: 100%;
}

.col-center {
  display: inline-block;
  word-spacing: normal;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
}
.col-center:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
```

I made an article about it and how it works: http://cahnory.tumblr.com/post/127631188627/effectively-remove-whitespaces-between