# Different margins in elements with inline-block

Tags: css, css-float

I'm switching divs from `float:left` to `inline-block` and don't know why some of the divs are displacing, like they have some invisible border or something.

Here are with `float:left` https://jsfiddle.net/f7op4dze/

```
div{
    background-color: red;
    width: calc(25% - 40px);
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 20px;
}
```

And here with `inline-block` https://jsfiddle.net/dfdxa5hc/

```
div{
    background-color: red;
    width: calc(25% - 40px);
    height: 50px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 20px;
}
```

Comment: Did you link the correct example? It looks like you might have forgotten to update your fiddle in the second version.

Comment: I think it's related to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: You are right! I have updated the second one. Thanks!

Comment: See the link posted by @Pangloss, but also here you have a [simple fix](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/dfdxa5hc/1/).

Comment: Thanks both for the info!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't these 4 inline-block boxes fit neatly in their container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801095/why-dont-these-4-inline-block-boxes-fit-neatly-in-their-container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one possible option to fix the problem, set the `font-size` of the parent to `0`.

```
section { font-size: 0; }
```

You can restore the font on the child elements:

```
div { font-size: 16px; }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dfdxa5hc/3/

For an explanation and other possible solutions, see my answer here:

- [inline-block boxes not fitting in their container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32801095/3597276)

Answer (score 2):

There's a space automatically added with inline elements and this space is applied to `inline-block` as well.

If there's no whitespace (either a space or a return) between the elements in your markup, the inline-block elements will be rendered without a space.

The easiest way to do this and still retain optimal formatting is using comment tags in between the `<div>` elements like so:
https://jsfiddle.net/orvn/wd0ynq98/2/

```
<section>
     <div></div><!--
  --><div></div><!--
  --><div></div><!--
  --><div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: That's one way to address the issue. But I wouldn't call it the *easiest* way. There are various other ways that are just as simple and easy, without sacrificing more in terms of formatting.

Comment: The challenge with `font-size: 0;` is that it becomes a hurdle if you want to render text in any of these elements. But I see what you mean. I like using `<!-- -->` because if you format it with the same indentation, the markup is easy to follow and hardly looks altered because most text editors will grey out the comment.

Comment: I just saw your other answer in the other question linked to above. I didn't know you can set the `font-size` of child elements back to normal after setting the parent to 0. Very cool. Your way is the most prudent.

Comment: Like I said, there are several options available. Both your answer and mine address the issue effectively. I only had a minor issue with calling the comment tag method the *easiest*. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There is (finally) a [CSS only solution to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32246845/2038942)

```
section {
  display: table;
  word-spacing: -2em;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  word-spacing: normal;
}
```